Search multiple keywords over a column and create columns for each
I have the following data.
stringstosearch <- c("to", "and", "at", "from", "is", "of")

set.seed(199)
datatxt <- data.frame(id = c(rnorm(5)), 
                       x = c("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.",
       "A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia",
       "It has roots in a piece of classical Latin ", 
       "literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.", 
       "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since"))

I want to search the keywords listed in stringtosearch and create columns for each with results.
I tried
library(stringr)
datatxt$result <- str_detect(datatxt$x, paste0(stringstosearch, collapse = '|'))

which returns
> datatxt$result
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

However, I am looking for an approach which creates a boolean vector for each word in stringstosearch, i.e.
          id                                                                  x    to   and    at  from    is    of
1 -1.9091427 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
2  0.5551667            A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 -2.2163365                        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  0.4941455              literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5 -0.5805710                       The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Any idea how to achieve this?

Here is a base R one-liner. Use sprintf() to add the \\b word boundary anchors to each pattern. This means that, for example, "and" will not match "random". Then iterate over these patterns with lapply(), using grepl() to match each pattern to datatxt$x. This returns a list of logical vectors, which we can assign back to the data frame.
datatxt[stringstosearch] <- lapply(
    sprintf("\\b%s\\b", stringstosearch), \(x) grepl(x, datatxt$x)
)

Now datatxt is as desired:
          id                                                                  x    to   and    at  from    is    of
1 -1.9091427 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2  0.5551667            A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 -2.2163365                        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4  0.4941455              literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5 -0.5805710                       The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

tidyverse approach
As you tagged tidyverse, here an alternative method. This returns the same list as the base R approach using tidyverse functions, except it's named. Then we can use the splice operator to pass this to dplyr::mutate() as new columns:
datatxt |>
    dplyr::mutate(
        !!!purrr::map(
            purrr::set_names(
                stringr::str_glue("\\b{stringstosearch}\\b"),
                stringstosearch
            ),
            \(str) stringr::str_detect(x, str)
        )
    )
# ^^ same output

I think the base R approach is much cleaner.

Cool! \(i) stringfish::sf_grepl(datatxt$x, i) might bring some speed-up if needed.

@Friede nice - I wasn't aware of that package. Is it faster? I  just looked it up and it seems to be optimised to handle ALTREPs but we don't have one here.

I guess. Well, we could try this out if we knew that OP's data was big.

I suggest Vectoriz[e]ing the pattern-argument of stringfish::sf_grepl():
Vsf_grepl = Vectorize(\(pattern) stringfish::sf_grepl(datatxt$x, pattern))
datatxt[stringstosearch] = Vsf_grepl(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", stringstosearch))

gives
> datatxt
  id                                                                  x    to   and    at  from    is    of
1  1 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2  2            A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  3                        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4  4              literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5  5                       The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Note, I changed id generation to id = 1:5.

I have a (different) tidyverse solution:
library(tidyverse)

stringstosearch <- c("to", "and", "at", "from", "is", "of")
strings <- c(
  "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.",
  "A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia",
  "It has roots in a piece of classical Latin ",
  "literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.",
  "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since"
)

datatxt <- tibble(
  id = seq_along(strings),
  x = strings,
  !!!stringstosearch %>% set_names()
) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      all_of(stringstosearch),
      ~ grepl(paste0("\\b",cur_column(),"\\b"), x, ignore.case = TRUE)
    )
  )

This code first creates the dataframe, using the !!! operator from tidyverse to create a column for each element in the stringstosearch vector. Without the set_names() function, the column names would be quoted. Then we mutate() across all of the columns determined by the elements of stringstosearch. For each column, we determine with grepl() whether the column name - retrieved within the call through cur_column() - exists in the x column, with "\\b" added to the regex to determine word boundaries and prevent false positives (as SamR pointed out).
Now datatxt outputs:
# A tibble: 5 × 8
     id x                                                                    to    and   at    from  is    of   
  <int> <chr>                                                                <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text." TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
2     2 "A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia"            FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
3     3 "It has roots in a piece of classical Latin "                        FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
4     4 "literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old."              FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
5     5 "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since"                       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 


You need to add \\b into your regex as at the moment you're returning the incorrect results, e.g. "and" has matched both "random" and "standard".

library(tidyverse)

stringstosearch <- c("to", "and", "at", "from", "is", "of") %>% 
  set_names()

set.seed(199)

datatxt <- data.frame(id = c(rnorm(5)), 
                      x = c("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.",
                            "A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia",
                            "It has roots in a piece of classical Latin ", 
                            "literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.", 
                            "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since"))

bind_cols(datatxt, imap(
  .x = stringstosearch,
  .f = ~ transmute(datatxt,!!.y := str_detect(x, glue::glue("\\b{.x}\\b")))
))
#>           id                                                                  x
#> 1 -1.9091427 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
#> 2  0.5551667            A Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia
#> 3 -2.2163365                        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin 
#> 4  0.4941455              literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
#> 5 -0.5805710                       The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since
#>      to   and    at  from    is    of
#> 1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#> 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 5 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Created on 2024-11-13 with reprex v2.0.2
